# Create non dismissible bottom sheet like GoogleMaps in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to show a bottom sheet exactly like the bottom sheet in google maps app (i mean the scrolling and expanding, dragging and dismising), how can I do so?

Basically i check for an `index` variable and if it's not `-1` then the bottom sheet is visible else some other widget is visible (like what happens in Gmaps).

`showModalBottomSheet()` and `showBottomSheet()` won't work because user needs to tap outside of bottom sheet (for example user select something on the map) correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/SalehTZ/c21fe5888818fcefd1b492cb60b8bf72) to my code gist.

This bottom sheet works fine but the problem is when user drags the BottomSheet with the grey handle or by BottomSheet title, BottomSheet doesn't expand or scroll. it's only expandable via the list inside the BottomSheet.

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.